# How to start zookeeper servers from java programming

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to start zoo keeper servers from my class the following way(and create some zk nodes),
but execution freezes on zk node creation:

```
serverExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    serverExecutor.execute(() -> {
        QuorumPeerMain.main(new String[]{"/usr/share/zookeeper- 
    3.4.6/conf/zoo1.cfg"});
    });

    serverExecutor.execute(() -> {
        QuorumPeerMain.main(new String[]{"/usr/share/zookeeper- 
    3.4.6/conf/zoo2.cfg"});
    });

serverExecutor.shutdown();

zkClient = new ZooKeeper(......
zkClient.create(..... **FREEZES HERE!**
```

Important notes:
I check *serverExecutor* some time later after execution and it is in running state, both threads are running.
If I run servers explicitly through terminal(with configs provided), than cluster works correctly, and my client successfully creates zk node.
Again, configuration is identical.
I even tried to start 3 servers.

Can you help me start servers from java code, and make them work in cluster.

Comment: In my team,we write scripts to start zookeeper and in java code to call the start script

Comment: @TongChen why not just start it from code?

Comment: First, a lot of action need to do; Second,it's a hard work to maintained in java codes.